# CSS Grid Elements Positioning on Window Resize

Tags: css, responsive, css-grid

> I have **4** divs, which on **medium** size windows look as bellow:

```
 ------------   ------------
| top-left    |  top right   |
 ------------   ------------
| bottom left |  bottom right|
 ------------   ------------
```

> Given the code snippet attached, on **small** devices, the following
>   positioning occurs:

```
 -------------  
| top-left    |  
 -------------   
| bottom left |  
 -------------   
| top-right   |  
 -------------   
| bottom right|  
 -------------
```

> My desired positioning is:

```
 -------------  
| top-left    |  
 -------------   
| top-right   |  
 -------------   
| bottom left |  
 -------------   
| bottom right|  
 -------------
```

**I would have expected that**

```
  grid-template-areas:
      'top-left-container'
      'top-right-container'
      'bottom-left-container'
      'bottom-right-container';
```

**would fulfill this, but it doesn't. 
Any ideas why and how can this be achieved?**

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-areas:
      'top-left-container top-right-container'
      'bottom-left-container bottom-right-container';
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      'top-left-container'
      'top-right-container'
      'bottom-left-container'
      'bottom-right-container';
  }
}
.left {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}

.right {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}

.top-left {
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: top-left-container;
  height: 100px;
}

.top-right {
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: top-right-container;
  height: 100px;
}

.bottom-left {
  background: red;
  grid-area: bottom-left-container;
}

.bottom-right {
  background: red;
  grid-area: bottom-right-container;
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="top-left">
      Top left
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">
      Bottom left
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="top-right">
      Top right
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-right">
      Bottom right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that you wrap each pair of elements with another `div`. Do you need the exact HTML structure?

Comment: not necessarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure what to do with borders, but basically you have to have the structure flat for the grid to work and apply each border side individually however you want.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-areas:
      'top-left-container top-right-container'
      'bottom-left-container bottom-right-container';
  }
  
  .top-left {
    border-top: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .top-right {
    border-top: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .bottom-left {
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .bottom-right {
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      'top-left-container'
      'top-right-container'
      'bottom-left-container'
      'bottom-right-container';
  }
  
  .top-left {
    border-top: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .top-right {
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .bottom-left {
    border-top: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
  }

  .bottom-right {
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
  }
}
.left {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}

.right {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}

.top-left {
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: top-left-container;
  height: 100px;
}

.top-right {
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: top-right-container;
  height: 100px;
}

.bottom-left {
  background: red;
  grid-area: bottom-left-container;
}

.bottom-right {
  background: red;
  grid-area: bottom-right-container;
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-left">
      Top left
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">
      Bottom left
    </div>
    <div class="top-right">
      Top right
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-right">
      Bottom right
    </div>
</div>
```